# Optimal leverage for short-only crypto strategy

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, leverage, cryptocurrency

I have the following strategy
Instrument : crypto pairs (50 coins) short only
,Markets : spot and futures (isolated margin account margin sell (for spot) and futures on Binance)
,Frequency : ~5-10 trades a day
,Hold time : few hours to 2-3 days
,Capital allocation : I allocate ~8% of total capital per position and I will have a maximum of 10 positions open at any given time. The strategy does not use stop or take profit. We open a position and whenever there is sell signal and close whenever there is a buy signal.

I am using really low leverage of 0.5x i.e. if I short sell 100 dollars worth of a coin, I allocate $200 margin to this isolated margin account (or for the futures trade in isolated mode).
This leverage allows the position to spike 160%-200% against our entry price before I get a margin call.
Assuming the strategy should generate a certain amount of return in an ideal scenario when no margin call is ever hit but obviously that will never be the case since crypto coins are subject to 2x-10x spikes so margin calls are inevitable which means the frequency of margin calls will seriously impact the expectation of this strategy.

I chose this amount of leverage for now because it 'seemed reasonable' but from the analysis I have done from the backtest,

> for some coins, I am still over leveraging because they are subject to 2x-5x(or even more) short term spikes(short squeezes and other reasons?) number of times in a year so no amount of margin allocation will save those positions from hitting margin call

> for some other coins, I seem to be under-leveraging as these coins are generally less volatile and I am thinking I could get away by leveraging a bit more but then I increase the risk of getting liquidated so I need to find the right balance

Can I please get advice on how to determine the optimal leverage per position so I can allocate margin appropriately.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the information you provided it is hard to suggest something specific but here are some general approaches you can take:

**1. Your model has expected return as a output**
If your model predicts the expected return of the investment (usually predictive models) you can use this number in **Kelly Criterion** to get the optimal leverage. There are few mathematical advantages of Kelly criterion such as maximizing wealth, avoiding bankruptcy by aggressively reducing position but you should also check it's practical limitations.

**2. Use some historical factor to determine leverage**
For example you can use drawdown from your backtest to decide what leverage suits you the most. More leverage for assets with smaller drawdown. Also, market regimes, instrument/sector volatility can also be a candidate. However, you will have to run backtest to see what works best and since it is based on historical data wouldn't guarantee same will apply in the future.